# is it possible to install an unsigned .ipa using a plist on a site without a jailbroken iphone

Tags: ios, xcode, plist, ipa

i have build an app using the ionic framework but i want to install it on an iphone. it has been tested throughly using an android phone, but paying $99 just so the app can be signed seems a bit outragious to me.

so therefore the question. is it possible to install an unsigned ipa file using an  on a site using a non-jailbroken phone?

i made the .plist file on the site and made a link

```
<a href="itms-services://?action=download-manifest&amp; 
url=https://site.url/location/to/plist/file.plist">
Download
</a>
```

Comment: It's possible, although not in the way you would from the AppStore; it would need to be sideloaded, and the app would also cease to work after a week or so (it would need to be reloaded). Also the person wanting to install the app would need to have specific software on their machine in order to install it.

Comment: for now that isn't a problem. it's a testing app for iphone. but is it possible using a site. or only using something like cydia impactor?

Comment: Huh? I don't think you are required to pay 99$ to sign and install on your device, you only need to buy that to access AppStore and other apple service for your app. Just create a developer account then you are good to go

Comment: i tried to build regular signed ipa's, but it wouldn't allow me cuz i wasn't in the apple developer program (which requires you to pay 99$)

Comment: @Benvo: I believe cydia impactor or Xcode would be the only way to do it for a non-jailbroken device.

Comment: I'm not sure about Ionic IDE, but both XCode and Visual studio can both build and install the app just fine with normal developer signing, debug mode only though

Comment: @Tj3n yeah, but the app is for my client and he is temporary in another country so i can't go to him and he wants to have it asap.

Comment: Ah then I think you are out of option here.

Comment: btw, the app isn't going in to the appstore after full release. it's for a company and they only want to use it in there, not outside of it. so thats the reason for an ipa and on-site plist installation.

Comment: You should ask for their enterprise account I guess? they are going to need it if they are going to publish in-house anyway

Comment: so why does apple have to be so greedy to developers unlike google.